# Remove Decimal trailing zeros without using scientific form in Elixir

Tags: elixir, decimal

I'd like to remove trailing zeros from the decimal part and keep the integer part in the neutral form (so not changing its from `100` to `1e2`. Using [Decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#reduce/1) properly removes trailing zeros but it switches to scientific notation as well.

```
iex(30)> d = Decimal.new("1.00000")
#Decimal<1.00000>
iex(31)> Decimal.reduce(d)
#Decimal<1>
iex(32)> d = Decimal.new("100.00000")
#Decimal<100.00000>
iex(33)> Decimal.reduce(d)
#Decimal<1E+2>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"100.00000" 
|> Decimal.new() 
|> Decimal.round(0) 
|> Decimal.to_integer 
|> Decimal.new()
```

equals

```
#Decimal<100>
```

I guess that's the route you should take. However, the representation of the decimal doesn't really matter, it's still the same format when stores, I believe. Unless this is about readability?

After some further investigation I noticed that the representation is not the same. 
Consider the following.

```
iex(35)> x = "100.0000000" |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(0) |> Decimal.to_integer |> Decimal.new()
#Decimal<100>
```

`x` is internally represented as `%Decimal{sign: 1, coef: 100, exp: 0}`.  This is in scientific notation `100 * 10^0` (i.e., `100 * 1`).

But if we just use the `reduce/1` function it is represented differently:

```
iex(50)> y = Decimal.new("100.0000000") |> Decimal.reduce()                                                
#Decimal<1E+2>
```

`y` is represented as `%Decimal{sign: 1, coef: 1, exp: 2}`. This is in scientific notation `1 * 10^2` (i.e., `1 * 100`).

These values are exactly the same, but are represented differently and are not equal in terms of `==`, either. They are the same using `Decimal.equal?/2`.

```
iex(64)> x == y
false
iex(65)> Decimal.equal?(x, y)
true
```

Final update: if this is about representation in textual form you can always use the `to_string/2` function and tell it to output "normal" representation.

```
iex(68)> y |> Decimal.to_string(:normal)
"100"
iex(69)> x |> Decimal.to_string(:normal)
"100"
```

All the options are listed here: https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#to_string/2

Comment: It is, I am going to send this value in email and don't want to use trailing zeros nor scientific notation

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `x == y` returns false because it compares underlying maps, and one cannot “overload” `Kernel.==/2` macro. [`Decimal.equal?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#equal?/2) would obviously return true.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I figured as much, but I included it for completeness. I added the equal? call too now,

Answer (score 0):

From: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#trunc/1

```
trunc(number)
```

Specs

```
trunc(number()) :: integer()
```

Returns the integer part of number.

Allowed in guard tests. Inlined by the compiler.

Examples:

```
iex> trunc(5.4)
> 5

iex> trunc(-5.99)
> -5

iex> trunc(-5)
> -5
```